# how we can use inheritance to access a parameter that is passed to a function with the same name but in two different classes?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I am new to inheritance and am trying to understand how we can use it to access a parameter that is passed to a function with the same name but in different classes.

For example:

```
class Subparser:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def test1(self, likes):
        self.likes = 72


class Parser(Subparser):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def test88(self):
        <how_can_I_access_self.likes_from_test1?>


B = Parser()
print(B.test1())
```

In the last line above, I am prompted to add one more argument into the `B.test1()` function, which makes sense as I need to fill in `likes` but my understanding is that since we have `test1` function in both Classes **with the same function name** - how can I use inheritance to access the `likes` parameter in `Subparser.test1` from `Parser.test1`?

i.e. my understanding is that when I run the above code, I should get 72 printed twice!!!

Comment: Why should you get `72`? The parameter you provided for `C.test1()` has nothing to do with `B.test1()`. `C` and `B` are two different instances.

Comment: Ahh okay, then a better question is- is it possible to access the `likes` parameter in `Subparser.test1()` from `Parser.test1()`??

Comment: No there is no way.  Inheritance doesn't grant access to values passed as instance method parameters.  In fact in your example the inheritance is doing nothing at all.  You overwrite the `test1` method so essentially there is nothing to inherit

Comment: Subclasses inherit the functions from the superclass and can add their own ones, but functions with the exact same signature are overwritten with the subclass ones. So in your example creating a Subparser object means it uses the function defined in Subparser. Creating a Parser object means it uses the function defined in the Parser class. If Subparser didn't declare the function and you would call it then it would use the Parser one. If Parser didn't declare the function and you would call it there would be an error.

Comment: `Parser().test1()` can call `super().test1(likes)` to access the parent method that it overrides.

Comment: Right. No matter how you call it, you need to pass `likes` as a parameter. It won't magically come from some other instance.

Comment: Okay, thank you both for the explanation- I have amended the code. Could you kindly advise how I can now access `likes` in `Parser.test88()`? If this is at all possible, unless Alexander is saying this is impossible.

Comment: No, it's not possible.  First, you aren't storing `likes` anywhere.  Once `C.test1` is finished, that value goes away, never to be seen again.  Even if you did do `self.likes = likes`, however, you still have a problem: you passed 72 to `C`.  `B` has its own copy of `test1`, but ITS `self.likes` will not have been initialized.  Even if you did `B = Subparser()`, it can't access member variables in a different object.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Is it possible to access `likes` if we were to store it somehow? I just need a way to access it from within Parser.test88(), all changes to the code is okay!

Comment: Maybe what you're messing is that `self.like`, if set, is an attribute _of the instance_ (in this case of `B`), not of the method that set it. If the method `test1()` is executed, and you can simply access it from `test88()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Maybe* you are looking for something like this, who knows?

```
class Subparser:

    def test1(self, like):
        self.like = like


class Parser(Subparser):

    def test88(self):
        return self.like


my_object = Parser()
my_object.test1(72)

print(my_object.test88())
```

If that's not what you want... well, maybe you need to read up on how classes work, and you'll be able to answer your own questions better.

Comment: Hi Alexis, this is almost what I am after! - but let's say you didn't know what `like` looks like? - in your code above you passed in 72 as the argument, but let's say we didn't know what this looks like, how would I initialise `my_object.test1()` or what would I pass into this?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure what you are trying to ask now. It is possible to inspect a variable from the interactive prompt, but this does not have a lot to do with your question. I do suggest you read up on your own so that you'll understand how these things really work, instead of trying to imagine the whole system.